# how to insert data in textbox on button click in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to show data on textbox when user click on button. I am using Asp Button and Asp Textbox **(in ASPX View Engine)** but Button Click event is not working in MVC4, its not calling any code or function on server side when i clicked on button.
Provide me any code in **ASPX View Engine** with simple one textbox and button. When user click on button it will insert data in textbox from server and Display an Alert showing 'Data is Inserted'. 
I have used

```
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub BtSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


        text_mess.Value = Nothing
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", "alert('Message Sent');", True)
    End Sub
</script>

<textarea id="text_mess"  runat="server" name="text_mess" draggable="false">
 Message
</textarea>
<br />
<asp:Button CssClass="login-submit" ID="BtSend" runat="server" Text="Send"
 OnClick="BtSend_Click"  />
```

Comment: write a js(jquery) code for ajax call and in case of success put data (perhaps alert) on button.

Comment: could you show some code?

Comment: I suggest you to study Asp.Net MVC, beacause it seems that your are going to wrong direction.